# Slang or idiom for submissive

Tags: slang, idiom-requests

Is there an idiomatic or slang word meaning *a submissive person* who does everything others order him to do and never complains even when they should, and is ,in a sense, controlled by someone else.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [many questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=doormat)

Comment: Lackey, pawn, tool, pet, lapdog.  The first and last are closest to what is requested.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [doormat](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doormat)

> one that submits without protest to abuse or indignities.

**An even better word is** [kowtower](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kowtow)

> someone who agrees too easily or eagerly to do what someone else wants you to do : to obey someone with power in a way that seems weak.

**But the best one is** [he/she is my bitch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bitch)

> A submissive person (often female), who does what others want.

Comment: I know you're just quoting wikitionary but (at least where I'm from) the bitch in "being somebody's bitch" is almost exclusively male. I'm not even certain if I've ever heard a female be called "somebody's bitch". Unless it's being used as slang for "girlfriend".

Answer (score 9):

[Pushover](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pushover)

> a person who is easily persuaded, influenced, or seduced.

You could also just refer to [puppet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/puppet) for your "controlled by" sense:

> a person, group, state, etc, that appears independent but is in fact controlled by another

Answer (score 4):

- **someone's bitch** (noun) could be used (where someone is a proper noun), though I don't like this phrasing
- One might say a person is **whipped** (adj.), particularly if referring to a romantic relationship
- **pushover** is probably the best noun

Comment: Please be wary of the previous answers. Except for "whipped," other two amswers have been posted. Duplicate answers are frowned upon. Seeing as you're new here, I hope you learn that quick.

Answer (score 2):

In the sense that an *alpha* is the dominant member of a group (as in *alpha male*), and a *beta* the alpha's lackey:

### omega

From [the Wikipeda article on Alpha (ethology)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_(ethology)):

> Omega … is an antonym used to refer to the lowest caste of the
>   hierarchical society. Omega animals are subordinate to all others in
>   the community, and are expected by others in the group to remain
>   submissive to everyone. Omega animals may also be used as communal
>   scapegoats or outlets for frustration, or given the lowest priority
>   when distributing food.

Admittedly, this usage is rare, though it should be clear to those familiar with this sense of *alpha* or *beta* (and that usage is common enough).

Comment: 'Beta' is the usual usage

Comment: @Mitch a beta, in turn, may lord over lesser minions. From the question, it seemed the person doesn't do any lording at all. But from the "controlled by someone else" part, a beta might be better.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider **[Yes-Man](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/yes-man)**, someone who automatically agrees with everything their superior(s) tell(s) them and only tells them what they want to hear.