# I am looking for a word (a noun preferably but an adjective would suffice) that denotes a person that knowingly allows another to use them regularly

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, nouns, poetry, attributive-nouns

This is for a poetic endeavor.

The person allowing this is a people pleaser and lacking in self-esteem (obviously). They feel they are in love with the “user” and although aware that the “relationship” is one-sided, they make excuses and would rather put up with being taken advantage of than lose them.  They believe that patience and perseverance will pay off in the end.

Comment: As too often happens on this site, the alleged duplicate is not adequate for the question. The question specifically mentions love, and there is no mention of love in any of the answers in the so-called duplicate. Reopen (not that I expect a flood of answers to appear).

Comment: I can't post an answer, for lack of reputation. Past participles like "enthralled" and "subjugated" might apply here, expecially for poetry. "Enthralled" in particular carries both the meaning "whose interest is captivated" and "who is enslaved".

Comment: Related: [A single word for "Someone who cannot say no to anyone asking for help."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143244/) and [Is there a single word or phrase for "inability to say no at a behavioural level"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174380/) and [Specific word or psychological term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/) Also [What do we call a person who is obedient to someone even though he knows that that person is taking advantage of him](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/528924/)

Comment: In my small research  I keep seeing "doormat" and "pushover" as the most popular suggestions, which don't quite do it for me. Related: [Slang or idiom for submissive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325711/) and [What's a word or phrase that means 'take advantage of someone's psychological weaknesses'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332261/) and [Is there a single word for "patience taken to the extreme"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/401002/) And, [One word for "being deceived into complying"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/442414/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can I suggest **milquetoast**?

> a timid, meek, or unassertive person

A milquetoast person *knows* they are being abused, but does nothing about it. I think it fits pretty well, though the word is often associated with cowardice.

Answer (score 46):

One possibility:

[Merriam-Webster *doormat*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doormat)
2: one that submits without protest to abuse or indignities

It's metaphoric extension of the basic meaning - someone who gets "walked on" a lot.

Comment: A good suggestion, if not perfect because of the weak association with love. But a quick look through so-called synonyms reveals none that satisfy better the required meaning. I suspect "doormat" may be as good as it gets.

Comment: My feeling is that "doormat" is often used of people in relationships ([example](https://www.thehartcentre.com.au/are-you-a-doormat-in-your-relationship/), [example](https://www.baggagereclaim.co.uk/dont-become-an-indispensable-doormat-in-order-to-keep-a-relationship/)), so while it doesn't have an obvious romantic meaning, it is often used in that way. It maybe relates to "walkover" which is a more general term for someone who poses no challenge (e.g. often used in sports).

Comment: I thought a person known as a doormat usually allows everyone to treat them poorly without any protests. He/she is not dedicated to any one person, love or otherwise.

Answer (score 17):

I would propose [pushover](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pushover) or [lapdog](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lapdog)

**Pushover**

> 3. someone unable to resist an attraction or appeal : sucker

**Lapdog**

> 2 : a servile dependent or follower

Answer (score 13):

A fashionable word is "simp". It refers to men who allow themselves to be used by women in the hope of receiving favours or approval.

The older meaning of this word is "simpleton", however in current usage, this has been pretty much usurped.

Here is an excerpt from an essay on the origin and meaning of the term.

The internet teen slang simp, as is true of many slang terms that go mainstream, appears to come directly from Black hip-hop slang—and it’s older than you may think.

> Hip-hop lyrics from the late 1980s and 1990s were already using simp
> as an insult for a men perceived as too subservient to a woman. For
> instance, on Ice-T’s 1987 “Our Most Requested Record [Long Version],”
> DJ Evil E raps: “Taking out all simps and suckers …” Urban Dictionary
> entries in the early 2000–2010s also use simp in this way
>
> https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/simp/

Comment: This is colloquial, however it captures the meaning of what the OP was asking for the closest in my opinion

Comment: I'm not sure how other people feel about this. But when hearing simp I primarily think of "Sucker ideolizing mediocre pussy" which would not be a good fit for the described situation. Actually, in my opinion, this is a word I would use never ever ever.

Comment: This is the word that first sprang to mind. I'd include the definition in your answer, not just the origin. The link you posted has it in there "Simp is a slang insult for men who are seen as too attentive and submissive to women, especially out of a failed hope of winning some entitled sexual attention or activity from them."

Answer (score 7):

Consider ***servile***:

> too eager to serve and please someone else in a way that shows you do not have much respect for yourself
> <sub>[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/servile)</sub>

Comment: I like this… it delivers without quite such a punch and leaves a little less of a negative connotative taste on the tongue.

Answer (score 6):

If the person is a man and the word can be a little vulgar then **pussy whipped** would be an option.

[The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pussy-whipped): "pussy whipped: (vulgar slang) Totally controlled, domineered, or emasculated by a woman. Typically said of a man. Sometimes hyphenated or written as a single word."

Answer (score 3):

### *subservient*

> She was subservient to her partner to a fault.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subservient) defines the term as

> <sub>*adjective*   • disapproving</sub>
> willing to do what other people want, or considering your wishes as less important than those of other people:
>
> - *Women were expected to adopt a subservient role/position*.

Answer (score 3):

Co-dependent — this was very popular in the 1980s.  I'm surprised it hasn't shown up yet.

From Mental Health America via Google:

> A tendency to do more than their share, all of the time. A tendency to become hurt when people don't recognize their efforts. An unhealthy dependence on relationships. The co-dependent will do anything to hold on to a relationship; to avoid the feeling of abandonment. An extreme need for approval and recognition.

Answer (score 2):

## enabler

The [Caimbridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/enabler) English Dictionary] defines "*enabler*".

You can read the definition from Caimbridge I supplied, or readthe following novel definition:

> For any two persons **x** and **y** if **x** provides somthing to **y** which **y** uses to damage themselves, then **x** is said to be an *enabler* of **y**.

An Example:

> Sarah was an *enabler* of her husband's gambling addiction. She even sold her mother's jewelry in order to supply him with more money.

Answer (score 1):

I immediately thought "tool", but that doesn't necessarily imply love as a motivator. Also, "tool" subtly implies not knowing you're being used (possibly willing disbelief), so that makes "tool" less favorable than "doormat".

But it might rhyme!

Comment: Tool also has a very different negative connotation.

Comment: I concur, but the OP didn't specify a positive or negative meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it always have to be one word with these posts? I just do not get it.

Nonetheless **obsequious** and **credulous** are the two words I should use to describe the person about whom you are talking.

Comment: The OP asked for one word. Are you asking about their motivation for the singleton request or just rhetorically commenting on your perception of the state of this community in general?

Comment: I think this is about the general case, by the use of the word "posts" (plural).

Answer (score 0):

A person who allows themselves to be used, perhaps with hope of a romantic pay-off is said to be  "***passive***".